# How to join multiple tables in CodeIgniter?

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter, join

I'm trying to join 3 or more table but its result showing from first two table only. Please help.

```
public function normal(){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('disease_db');
   $this->db->join('suggestion_db', ' suggestion_db.did=disease_db.id');
   $this->db->join('hospital_db', ' hospital_db.special_in=disease_db.id ');
   $this->db->where('disease_db.id',1);
   $result=  $this->db->get();
   print_r ($result->result_array());
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? It is likely there are fields with the same name (like "id") in your tables. Try `echo $this->db->last_error();`. There should be no problem joining 3 or more tables, I do it all the time.

Comment: @jtheman no there is not any errors. and its not working. there is not same name id too

Comment: Just curious, what will happen if you run this query in your database,  select *
from disease_db
inner join suggestion_db
on suggestion_db.did = disease_db.id
inner join hospital_db
on  hospital_db.special_in=disease_db.id
where disease_db.id = 1

Comment: To help you further, please try what @Jaaaaaaay suggested, and also please add your database schema, that would help to see what could affect this. There are really no reason for that the join should fail with more than two tables involved.